# DHCP Binary Value

Tags: networking, network-programming, dhcp

Is there anyway to read in the DHCP lease information completely that you received at login/connection to the server for a windows client? I have been looking around for this and appear to be stumped. Mainly looking to grab the IP lease returned by DHCP Server, and get the binary extraction from that if at all possible.

Comment: For what purpose? DHCP is none of your business really.

Comment: Need to receive what option has been sent and received for a greater purpose of communication between a server even if the WAN goes down. There's more that has to be done with the information, but I need to be able to grab it and store it at client boot.